# TS2749: 'XXX' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof XXX'?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, typescript-typings, vue-test-utils

I'm having quite a weird error when running my `npm run dev` developed using `Nuxt.js`, which has `Vue.js` components. Namely, when running the app, I'm seeing errors related to `TypeScript` such as `TS2749: 'About' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof About'?`, even though `npm run test` doesn't show anything.

My **spec.ts** file with complaining line

```
import { shallowMount, Wrapper } from "@vue/test-utils";    
import About from "@/pages/about.vue";

describe("About", () => {
  const wrapper: Wrapper<About> = shallowMount(About); // <-- Complaining line
  ...
}
```

The type should be fine when highlighting before setting typing, it shows me the type below.

[image]

The suggested solution with `const wrapper: Wrapper<typeof About> = shallowMount(About);` generates yet another `TypeScript` error causing the test not compiling. Namely, `TS2344: Type 'ExtendedVue<Vue, unknown, unknown, { setLocation: any; }, unknown>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Vue'. Type 'VueConstructor<{ setLocation: any; } & Vue>' is missing the following properties from type 'Vue': $el, $options, $parent, $root, and 32 more.`

I'm not sure why `test` is silent, whereas `TypeScript` starts complaining when running the app locally about the tests themselves. They're all passing btw, and the app compiles. It's simply related to some kind of `TypeScript`'s typings in `@vue/test-utils`.

Comment: Why do you even type the `wrapper` when it seems TS is perfectly able to infer the type ?

Comment: for explicit typing

Comment: The typing is explicit - it comes from `@vue/test-utils`. Duplicate the typing in your own code feels wrong...

Comment: Well, I've removed it to have a clear console. However, if the types are the same for readability & documentation I'd prefer to use explicit types, and it shouldn't cause anything in the console. Especially, if the tests don't show anything, and `npm run dev` does.

Comment: Well test runing fine is really strange because `Wrapper<About>` is really NOT valid TS type definition. Anything inside `<>` must by TS type - `About` is not TS type, it is really a value (Vue component definition object)

Comment: It was a typo, fixed!:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Wrapper<About>` is really a problem - this is TS type definition and `About` is not TS type...it is really a value (Vue component definition object).

Try `Wrapper<InstanceType<typeof About>>`

Explicitly declaring types coming from external library (with typings) and in fact ignoring TS type inference feels like a lot of unnecessary work. And to do that you should study and understand the [typings](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/blob/dev/packages/test-utils/types/index.d.ts)

...which I frankly do not in full ...so the code above can be wrong :)

Comment: It clarifies, thanks. Mostly, I try to have explicit typing for code readability, but apparently, here I was wrong.

Comment: PS. `Wrapper<typeof About & Vue>` return the same issue as in the question :)

Comment: `Wrapper<InstanceType<typeof About>>` works